# BulkCopy WriteToServer() Inserts Into Wrong Column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to write a `DataTable` into my destination table on Sql Server. DataTable `dt` only contains one column and its called `Email`. My destination table contains `tpid`, `lastname`, `age`, `date` and `email`.
This is the code I am using for bulk copy:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlCs))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    }
}
```

What I see is that in my destination table, I get the value of Email from my DataTable being inserted into the `tpid` column instead of `email`. I am using no column mapping here, but shouldn't bulk copy match *Email* with *email* automatically?

Answer (score 7):

Consider trying this mapping:

```
SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapMAIL = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Email", "email");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapMAIL);
```

You can query the MySQL schema for the source and destination tables and generate automappings based on field names, if you want.

Comment: but the column names are variable every time. This was just an example of the problem.

Comment: @Pedram, the default behavior of SqlBulkCopy is to map by ordinal.  You'll need to use the SqlBulkCopyMappings if you want to map by name.

Comment: Maybe you can do a query like `SHOW COLUMNS FROM _tablename_` to both the source and destination tables, then automatically generate mappings whilst being case insensitive? Something else you could try (which I don't know if you have) is seeing if it automatically maps "email" to "email" (case sensitive).

Answer (score 2):

no it won't match. you have to add mappings:

```
 myBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Email", "email"));
```

or source and destination have the same columns in the same order. if you need more flexibility i would recommend to implement a IDataReader and pass that to the WriteToServer method.